# How to use two variable in one foreach?

Tags: php

Im want to generate the Boostrap Acordion with 2 diferent taxonomies (var). But Im not able to Combine both in one Foreach.  Also I look in this Forum and I try some of the anwers but I just get errors.

```
<?php

$temporada = 'temporada';
$capitulo = 'capitulo';
$tax_temporada = get_terms($temporada);
$tax_capitulo = get_terms($capitulo);

foreach ($tax_temporada as $tax_temporada) {
echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
echo '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="c'. $tax_capitulo->name.'">';
echo '<h4 class="panel-title">' . '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'. $tax_temporada->name.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="' . $tax_temporada->name.'" >Temporada: ' . $tax_temporada->name.'</a></h4>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="'. $tax_temporada->name.'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="c'. $tax_capitulo->name.'">';
echo '<div class="panel-body">';
echo 'Capitulo '. $tax_capitulo->name.' ';
echo '</div>'.'</div>'.'</div>';

}
?>
```

The Problem Is I just can get One Var And not Both

This One here fix the Problem but The thing is Im not able to more than 1 $capitulo inside of each $temporada

```
<?php

$temporada = 'temporada';
$capitulo = 'capitulo';
$tax_temporada = get_terms($temporada);
$tax_capitulo = get_terms($capitulo);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tax_temporada); $i++) {
echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
echo '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="c'. $tax_capitulo[$i]->name.'">';
echo '<h4 class="panel-title">' . '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'. $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="' . $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" >Temporada: ' . $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'</a></h4>';
echo '</div>';
 //Here Start the $capitulos that go inside of every $temporadas 
echo '<div id="'. $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="c'. $tax_capitulo[$i]->name.'">';
echo '<div class="panel-body">';
echo 'Capitulo '. $tax_capitulo[$i]->name.' ';
echo '</div>'.'</div>'.'</div>';

}
?>
```

Comment: So where is the problem ?

Comment: I am not sure if this part is correct: `foreach ($tax_temporada as $tax_temporada) {` usually its `foreach ($something as $somethingelse)`

Comment: The Problem Is I just can get One Var And not Both

Comment: you can't, really. foreach loops on a SINGLE item. you can nest the loops, or if the arrays have a 1:1 correspondence in their key value/positions, then `foreach($one as $key => $value) { $otherval = $two[$key]; }` would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are both of these going to be arrays of objects, of the same length? If so, you could consider doing a simple `for` loop, as such:

```
<?php

$temporada = 'temporada';
$capitulo = 'capitulo';
$tax_temporada = get_terms($temporada);
$tax_capitulo = get_terms($capitulo);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tax_temporada); $i++) {
    echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
    echo '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="c'. $tax_capitulo[$i]->name.'">';
    echo '<h4 class="panel-title">' . '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'. $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="' . $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" >Temporada: ' . $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'</a></h4>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id="'. $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="c'. $tax_capitulo[$i]->name.'">';
    echo '<div class="panel-body">';
    echo 'Capitulo '. $tax_capitulo[$i]->name.' ';
    echo '</div>'.'</div>'.'</div>';

}
?>
```

Comment: it's the same thing as doing foreach($tax_temporada as $tax_temp)

Comment: The difference is that a `for` loop has a counter variable, and while a `foreach` _can_ have one, it's dependant upon the order of the keys present in the variable being iterated over.

Comment: This One Help Me, But Just show 1 $capitulo for each $temporada I trying to show lots of $capitulos for each $temporada

Comment: @V13Axel what about foreach($a as $key=>$value) ? You can have the key this way of each value, it's the same result but I think foreach is clearer and cleaner

Comment: I Edited With more info, to see.. I try to add another for, but that broke the code.

Answer (score 0):

The [MultipleIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) allows you to loop over several arrays at the same time

```
$tax_temporada = get_terms($temporada);
$tax_capitulo = get_terms($capitulo);

$taxIterator = new MultipleIterator();
$taxIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($tax_temporada));
$taxIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($tax_capitulo));
foreach($taxIterator as list($temporada, $capitulo)) {
   ... do what you want here with $temporada and $capitulo
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that unpacking nested arrays with list() requires PHP >= 5.5.0